# Always fetch from related models in Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I would like `baffle.where({id: 1}).fetch()` to always get `typeName` attribute as a part of `baffle` model, without fetching it from `baffleType` explicitly each time.

The following works for me but it seems that `withRelated` will load relations if `baffle` model is fetched directly, not by relation:

```
let baffle = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    constructor: function() {
        bookshelf.Model.apply(this, arguments);

        this.on('fetching', function(model, attrs, options) {
            options.withRelated = options.withRelated || [];
            options.withRelated.push('type');           
        });
    },

    virtuals: {
        typeName: {
            get: function () {
                return this.related('type').attributes.typeName;
            }
        }
    },
    type: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(baffleType, 'type_id');
    }
});

let baffleType = bookshelf.Model.extend({});
```

What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is super old, but I'm answering anyway.

I solved this by just adding a new function, `fetchFull`, which keeps things pretty DRY.

```
let MyBaseModel = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  fetchFull: function() {
    let args;
    if (this.constructor.withRelated) {
      args = {withRelated: this.constructor.withRelated};
    }
    return this.fetch(args);
  },
};

let MyModel = MyBaseModel.extend({
    tableName: 'whatever',
  }, {
    withRelated: [
      'relation1',
      'relation1.related2'
    ]
  }
);
```

Then whenever you're querying, you can either call `Model.fetchFull()` to load everything, or in cases where you don't want to take a performance hit, you can still resort to `Model.fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks, it is never too late.

Answer (score 8):

Issue on repo is related to `Fetched` event, However `Fetching` event is  working fine `(v0.9.2)`.

So just for example if you have a 3rd model like

```
var Test = Bookshelf.model.extend({
   tableName : 'test',
   baffleField : function(){
       return this.belongsTo(baffle)
   } 
})
```

and then do `Test.forge().fetch({ withRelated : ['baffleField']})`, `fetching` event on baffle will fire. However `ORM` will not include `type` (sub Related model) unless you specifically tell it to do so by

```
Test.forge().fetch({ withRelated : ['baffleField.type']})
```

However I would `try to avoid` this if it is making `N Query` for `N records`.

**UPDATE 1**

I was talking about same thing that you were doing on `fetching` event like

```
fetch: function fetch(options) {
   var options = options || {}
   options.withRelated = options.withRelated || [];
   options.withRelated.push('type');    
    // Fetch uses all set attributes.
   return this._doFetch(this.attributes, options);
}
```

in `model.extend`. However as you can see, this might fail on `version` changes.

Comment: Good point on `fetching`, thanks. So, is modifying `options.withRelated` the only option here if I want to keep business logic DRY and skip `{ withRelated: ... }` part on all `fetch()` calls? Performance is not critical in this part of the app.

Comment: @estus I think Yes. However I have been using sequelize  for sometime, so can not be sure. Another way of doing the same thing is ```overriding```(not a good word for JS) fetch method in ```model.extend```. However working with ```fetching``` event  is more of a bookshelf way of doing it. Overriding a method is more of a cleaner way but it might fail on version upgrades/downgrades.

Comment: It looks like `fetching` is triggered but no nested relations are loaded when 'baffle' is loaded as a relation, so `fetching` should be specified in each parent model. Could you please add an example for overriden `fetch`? Should it be something like `fetch: function (...args) { return bookshelf.Model.prototype.fetch.bind(this)(...args) }` ?

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, I guess that's the reason why `_doFetch` is there.